# Bulk assign Prestashop products to a category only if product status is activated

Tags: prestashop, categories, assign, bulk

**EDIT : I've found a solution, you can find it at the end of this question :) !**

I'm using Prestashop 1.6.1.5 on a site. I would like to bulk assign all products that have an active status to the category with id = 3. I also would like that the positions of the products in this category starts at 0 and increment.

Right now here is what I've done :

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO ps_category_product SELECT 3, id_product, ((SELECT MAX(position) FROM ps_category_product WHERE id_category = 3) + (@inc := @inc + 1)) FROM ps_product INNER JOIN (SELECT @inc := 0) AS i
```

In creates a new entry in the ps_category_product table for each product, associated to the id_category = 3. Each entry has an incremented position value.

But now, I only want the product that are active... If I add "WHERE active=1" at the end of the request, it creates the good entries only for active product BUT the position field is equal to 0 for every entry...

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO ps_category_product SELECT 3, id_product, ((SELECT MAX(position) FROM ps_category_product WHERE id_category = 3) + (@inc := @inc + 1)) FROM ps_product INNER JOIN (SELECT @inc := 0) AS i WHERE active = 1
```

What's wrong ?

How could I do that ?

**EDIT : HERE IS A SOLUTION !**

In fact, it seems that even my first query was not working properly for the position incrementation.

So finally I found a new solution. If someone want to use it, please don't forget to test it on a development site, I'm not responsible if something goes wrong ;) !

So let's say we want to bulk assign all the active products to a category with ID = 3.

1. In your DB, go to ps_category_product and delete all the entries where id_category = 3
2. Insert all active products in category=3

   INSERT IGNORE INTO ps_category_product SELECT 3, id_product, 0 FROM ps_product WHERE active=1
3. Increment product's position from 0 to X

   SELECT @i := -1;
   UPDATE `ps_category_product` SET `position`=(select @i := @i + 1) WHERE `id_category`=3;

I hope this could help someone :) !

Cédric

Comment: What did you try? There are many mass edition modules available on Prestashop addons. Developers at noomiastudio can't write a simple script like this on their own? ;). Please come back with some code or this question will be deleted.

Comment: Sorry @Florian Lemaitre, I've just updated my question ! Thank you in advance !